# Why do people use atomic exchange instead of store?

Tags: c++, atomic

That is C++

```
atomic_int turn(0)

turn.exchange(1);
turn.store(1);
```

this two code works same way, right?
But I checked many examples about lock use 1st one.

Why?

Comment: They don't work the same way. Yes, both replace the value but atomic::exchange also returns the value it had before the call. Anyway, it's too general to say "many examples about lock use 1st one." Showing some of these examples would help us understand if there is a reason why the first one is chosen.

Answer (score 3):

Both statements store a value into the atomic variable. The `exchange` call returns the previously held value, which, in this case, is discarded. However, this does not mean the two calls are exactly the same. The `exchange` operation is a read-modify-write operation, while the `store` operation is only a write. That means that if we have:

```
// thread 1
turn.store(0);  // A

// thread 2
turn.exchange(1);  // B
```

and if thread 2 reads the value stored by thread 1, then line A synchronizes with line B. If thread 2 were to use `store` rather than `exchange`, there would be no such synchronization.

Comment: I think this answer needs to say more about the consequences of "line A synchronizes with line B".

Comment: "_if thread 2 reads the value stored by thread 1_" If a tree falls in the forest and the return value is ignored, where is the tree?

Comment: This is a good explanation that shows the use of exchange.